# How to correctly set a Variant published property

Tags: delphi, types, properties, set, variant

I'm writing a component that publishes a Variant property named "Value".
In the object inspector window I can see the property and its Type.

[image]

Sometimes, after selecting the Type "String" from the drop down list, it turns to "unknown".

[image]

Here's code of the setter method:

```
procedure TMyComponent.FSetValue(const AValue : Variant);
begin
  if(FValue <> AValue) OR (TVarData(FValue).VType <> TVarData(AValue).VType) then
  begin
    FValue := AValue;
    if(@FOnChanged <> nil)
    then FOnChanged(Self);
  end;
end;
```

Is there something that should be changed?

**Further Informations:**

When "unknown" type appears, the type of AValue param is set to 256.

In System.pas I found this:

varString   = $0100; { Pascal string  256 } {not OLE compatible }

..but I still can't understand why "unknown" is shown..

Comment: Is FOnChanged declared as TNotifyEvent?  If so, why use @FOnChanged?  Remove the @ sign and try again?

Comment: @JSON - that would attempt to call FOnChanged, and fail to compile as there are no parameters. Use `Assigned(FOnChanged)` instead, that's what `Assigned()` was created for in the first place

Comment: @Jason: Sure, FOnChanged is TNotifyEvent but it's not influencing the behavior. 

    //if(@FOnChanged <> nil)
    //then FOnChanged(Self);

Type "unknown" still appears in the object inspector.. Is there a reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be because the function TVariantTypeProperty.GetValue in DesignEditors reads the type from the Variant value and then tries to look it up in a limited list which seems to only cover OLE compatible variants plus a specific exception for UniCode string.  The code for TVariantTypeProperty.SetValue translates "string" to type varString which appears to be a proxy for an old style AnsiString rather than a modern UniCode string.  GetValue translates type varUString to display the type as string and leaves varString as "unknown".  This looks like a bug in the Delphi design interface as there really shouldn't be any disparity between the GetValue and SetValue methods.

I have checked this on XE2 only so don't know which other versions may / may not be affected although you can reasonably construe that at least all previous versions since the Unicode conversion are affected.

Comment: I also checked this on XE7 and behavior/bug is still the same.
Is there a workaround to avoid "unknown" type appears?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only work around I could find was to assign a string value to Value. Like this.

```
procedure TMyComponent.FSetValue(const AValue : Variant);
  begin
    if(FValue <> AValue) OR (TVarData(FValue).VType <> TVarData(AValue).VType) then
      begin
        FValue := AValue;

          case TVarData(FValue).VType of
            varString : FValue := VarToStr( AValue ); //converts FValue to a string
          end;

         if(@FOnChanged <> nil) then 
           FOnChanged(Self);
      end;
  end;
```